# Counting uneven bins in Panda

Tags: python, pandas

```
pd.DataFrame({'email':["a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com", "c@gmail.com", "d@gmail.com", "e@gmail.com",],
                  'one':[88, 99, 11, 44, 33],
                  'two': [80, 80, 85, 80, 70],
                   'three': [50, 60, 70, 80, 20]})
```

Given this DataFrame, I would like to compute, for each column, one, two and three, how many values are in certain ranges.

The ranges are for example: 0-70, 71-80, 81-90, 91-100

So the result would be:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'colname': ["one", "two", "three"],
                   'b0to70': [3, 1, 4],
                   'b71to80': [0, 3, 1],
                   'b81to90': [1, 1, 0],
                   'b91to100': [1, 0, 0]})
```

What would be a nice idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would do it:

```
out = pd.DataFrame()
for name in ['one','two','three']:
    out[name] = pd.cut(df[name], bins=[0,70,80,90,100]).value_counts()
out.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Returns:

```
           one  two  three
(0, 70]      3    1      4
(70, 80]     0    3      1
(80, 90]     1    1      0
(90, 100]    1    0      0
```

Comment: instead of external for loop use the builtin apply i.e `df.set_index('email').apply(pd.cut,bins=[0,70,80,90,100]).apply(pd.value_counts)`

Comment: Thanks @Dark that's a great tip!

Comment: @Dark Awesome solution!